# target refreshing an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two frames, nav.html and main.html and they are contained in a page called index.html. I have three image links, back, forward, and refresh. The main.html iframe has a id="main" and the button have the respective targets. 
 
The forward and back work fine, but the refresh just refreshes the nav.html frame instead of the main.html frame. The code for index is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="nav.html" id="nav" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" width="19%" height="512"
align="left">
</iframe>

<iframe src="main.html" id="main" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" width="80%"
height="800" align="middle">
</iframe>
</div>
</html>
```

And here is the code for nav.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>navigation</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="nav/logo.png">
</center>
<center>

<a href="main.html" target="main">&lt;&frasl; Home &gt;</a>
<br><br>
//My general links

<br><br><br>
<a target="main" href="javascript: location.reload();"><img src="nav/refresh2.png"></a>
<a target="main" href="javascript: history.back();"><img src="nav/back2.png"></a>
<a target="main" href="javascript: history.forward();"><img src="nav/forward2.png"></a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to reload main page from iframe use this JavaScript:

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

and you can use this if you want to reload frame from other frame:

```
parent.frames['yourFrameName'].location.reload();
```

Comment: Tried the second one, which is what i'm looking for, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload main frame from nav frame

Then try parent.main.reload();

-Sridhar